# List weekday dates with certain dates excluded

Tags: date, google-sheets

I'd like to create a list of dates in column B, beginning with a user inputted date in B1. Each subsequent row will then display the date of the following weekday, however I will also have a shorter column (column A) where each row contains a date that should not be displayed in column B (even if it's a weekday). If the date that's going to display in column B is anywhere in column A, then that date will be skipped and the next non-excluded weekday's date will display instead.

It's essentially a list of weekday dates (column B) with holiday dates (column A) excluded.

So far, if I enter my start date in B1 and this formula in B2:

`=IF(WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE(B1+1),2) < 6,B1+1,IF(WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE(B1+2),2) < 6, B1+2, "N/A"))`

then it will cascade a list of all weekday dates, but I'm unsure of how to exclude my list of dates in column A. I'm also unsure if this is even the best way to start listing weekday dates, so any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Basic spreadsheet use isn't programming, this belongs on SU.

Comment: If you want to debate bigger issues about the topicality of a question/topic please use MSO to do it, not comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=WORKDAY(B1,1,A:A)
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be something that could help you get started

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(C:C)=1,"Filtered list",IF(countif($A:$A,$B1:B)>0,"",$B1:B)))
```

Try that in cell C1
It then creates a list based from column B, with dates from column A removed.